# How does decimal work?

Tags: c#, decimal

I looked at decimal in C# but I wasnt 100% sure what it did.
Is it lossy? in C# writing `1.0000000000001f+1.0000000000001f` results in `2` when using `float` (`double` gets you `2.0000000000002` which is correct) is it possible to add two things with decimal and not get the correct answer?

How many decimal places can I use? I see the MaxValue is `79228162514264337593543950335` but if i subtract 1 how many decimal places can I use?

Are there quirks I should know of? In C# its 128bits, in other language how many bits is it and will it work the same way as C# decimal does? (when adding, dividing, multiplication)

Comment: Is it lousy? Perhaps you should understand what it's trying to do before you write it off like that.

Comment: Or you should at least try using the type that you're complaining about, before calling it lousy :)

Comment: @Jon - this question is terribly worded, but I believe he's asking if `decimal` is "lousy" like `float` because adding a `float` is sometimes not "correct"

Comment: @John: Possibly. If that's the case, it really is *very* badly worded.

Comment: I think he means "lossy"

Comment: @David & @Jon: Maybe i should have said "is it lossless when doing addition and subtraction". The value is large so it would be hard to lose data on multiplication. Division i always assume will lose data.  -edit- Davy8! Thats the word! oops, it Lossy!

Comment: @acid @Jon That's a funny one! Lossy and lousy, so close in spelling and yet so far apart in meaning!

Comment: btw @John Rasch, thats exactly what i was asking. Jon comment in his answer about addition was important too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you're showing isn't `decimal` - it's `float`. They're very different types. `f` is the suffix for `float`, aka [`System.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx). `m` is the suffix for `decimal`, aka [`System.Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx). It's not clear from your question whether you thought this was actually using `decimal`, or whether you were just using `float` to demonstrate your fears.

If you use 1.0000000000001m + 1.0000000000001m you'll get exactly the right value. Note that the `double` version wasn't able to express either of the individual values exactly, by the way.

I have articles on both kinds of floating point in .NET, and you should read them thoroughly, along other resources:

- [Binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) (float/double)
- [Decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) (decimal)

All floating point types have their limits of course, but in particular you should *not* expect binary floating point to accurately represent decimal values such as 0.1. It still can't represent anything that isn't exactly representable in 28/29 decimal digits though - so if you divide 1 by 3, you won't get the exact answer of course.

You should also note that the *range* of `decimal` is considerably smaller than that of `double`. So while it can have 28-29 decimal digits of precision, you can't represent truly huge numbers (e.g. 10<sup>200</sup>) or miniscule numbers (e.g. 10<sup>-200</sup>).

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to comment? Due to me possibly misreading the question? I'm about to edit.

Comment: I'll bet Downvoter doesn't know C# has a decimal floating point type.

Comment: 1<sup>200</sup> isn't a particularly huge number.  Did you mean 10<sup>200</sup> and 10<sup>-200</sup>?

Comment: I notice you wanted to know when i updated my question. Bump. You caught the f which i meant as float. I only realized now some people thought i was talking about decimal. Mostly i wanted to know if its lossy or lossless (i'll exclude division and really really big numbers as the MaxValue is really high)

Comment: @acidzombie24: You'd have to define what you mean by "lossless" *really* carefully. It's pretty easy to exceed 28/29 digits after a few operations...

Comment: really. thats good to know. So i tested `1.0000000000000000000000000001m+1.0000000000000000000000000001m` and got the correct answer. If i add another zero i get 1 and no compile error but at least for addition and subtraction in the decimal range the answer appears to always be correct

Comment: @acidzombie24: On the other hand, try adding 10000000000000000000000000000m and 0.00000000000000000000001m together and you *won't* get the right result. Both values are within the range of decimal, but the answer can't be expressed exactly.

Comment: Funny, i havent been on SO for the last 40mins and now when i visit this page it says you replied 16secs ago.

This is exactly what i wanted to know. I would never have expected that until i debug a problem. Accepted & +1. Good answer.

Comment: I believe the person is trying to understand the underlying connection between float and decimal. Given it's label "decimal" one can rationally make the speculation that the two are related. The poster was down voted for lack of clarity.

Comment: @ShaneKelsey: I'm not sure what your comment was particularly aimed at, but the OP accepted this answer and said it was exactly what he wanted to know...

Answer (score -4):

Decimals in programming are (almost) never 100% accurate. Sometimes it's even better to multiply the decimal value with a very high number and then calculate, but that's only if you're for example sure that the value is always between 0 and 100(so it won't get out of range of the maxvalue)

Comment: The Decimal type in C# is not the same thing as a floating point number.

Comment: @TheBigO: Yes it is. `Decimal` is a floating point type. It's a *decimal* floating point type, but that's a different matter.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Technically you're right. So I'll amend my statement to be: Decimal types are represented differently from floats in C#.

Comment: @Martinho: Or to put it another way, double and float are *also* 100% accurate, in that each float or double value is an exact value, precisely represented. It's *operations* on those values which aren't 100% accurate :)

Answer (score -4):

Floting point is inherently imprecise. Some numbers can't be represented faithfully. Decimal is a large floating point with high precision. If you look on [the page at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) you can see there are "28-29 significant digits." The .net framework classes are language agnostic. they will work the same in every language that uses .net.

edit (in response to Jon Skeet): If you initialize the Decimal class with the numbers above, which are less than 28 digits each after the decimal point, the number will be stored faithfully as long as the binary representation is exact. Since it works in 64-bit format, I assume the 128-bit will handle it perfectly fine. Some numbers, such as 0.1, will never be exactly representable because they are a repeating sequence in binary.

Comment: Decimal can handle this situation easily - it's got plenty of precision, and it's in the right base. Shame the OP isn't actually *using* decimal. I haven't downvoted this answer yet, but it should really be updated as it gives the impression that this calculation - when performed in decimal - would still be inaccurate. It wouldn't be - it would be guaranteed to give exactly the right answer.

Comment: "Decimal is a larger version of the floating point standard." No it isn't. Decimals and floats represent their data differently.

Comment: this answer is not very correct, the c# codes has 2 type for situation DO NOT CONFUSE!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @PRASHANT P I have no idea what you are talking about.                   @TheBigO you are right, updated

Comment: you say decimal class, then 0.1 will never be exact representable because they are a repeating sequence in binary - that is same as say 1 is not representable by int. decimal is stored as base 10 number not 2 like in imaginary :)

Comment: PRASHANT is right - I hadn't spotted the final number. 0.1 *is* exactly representable in decimal, precisely because it's a floating *decimal* point rather than a floating *binary* point. 0.1 is just a mantissa of 1 with an exponent of -1, effectively.