# How to increase precision of double type for large numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, double, precision

In this sample code

```
double number = 2646849856355434345;
Console.WriteLine( number % 5 );
```

If I use Double for this operation, it won't give a precise answer. Here it will output "1" where it should output "0".

Is there anyway to increase the precision for large double numbers ?

Note: 
I know about BigInteger and I can use them but BigInteger takes long time and I'm wondering If I can have the same precision with doubles.

Comment: How about using `Decimal`? I believe it has bigger precision than `Double`.

Comment: Yes, decimal has about 29 digits precision.

Comment: You cannot change the `double` data type, you can only switch to a different data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx).

It is suitable for financial and monetary calculations.
Double is based on IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic ([IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)).

If you want to know the differences between binary floating point and decimal floating point read the following articles ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5046275/3970411)).

[Binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) (float/double)
[Decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) (decimal)

Answer (score 1):

`Double` should not be used for operations that require decimal precision you should use the [Decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) data type for decimal arithmetic.

The `Double` data type is precise only for binary arithmetic, being based on binary floating points it is impossible for it to be 100% precise for decimal arithmetic.